# show 2 different tables using ng-repeat using custom directives

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a custom directive(That generates a table) that is repeating twice on my index page. The values of the tables is populated via $scope.globalrows  variable. Even though the globalrows contains 2 array values, it always prints the second value. How do I modify my template or directives to show values unique to that table and prevent overwriting of the contents.

Issue:
The tables are repeating twice with the second table contents in the globalarray. I see the second table is overwriting the first table.

### index.html

```
<grid-print section="1"></grid-print>
<grid-print section="2"></grid-print>
```

### template : print.dir.html

```
<form class="form-horizontal clearfix">
    <table class="grid table table-bordered">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th ng-repeat="col in cols">{{col.title}}</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
          <tr ng-repeat="row in globalrows track by $index" index={{index}}>
            <td ng-repeat="col in cols">          
              <span>{{ row[col.field] }}</span>
            </td>  
          </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
    </form>
```

### directive:

```
.directive("gridPrint", function($sessionStorage, dataservice) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: "components/print/templates/print.dir.html",
        replace: true,
        controller: function($scope, $state, $attrs) {
            //array of the items that are to be displayed on the 2 tables  
            $scope.globalrows = dataservice.getCollectionData();          

        },
        link: function(scope, element, attributes){
           // console.log("in grid print"+attributes['section']);            
        }
    };
})
```

Another directive that generates rows, cols:

```
.directive("grid", function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: "components/section/directives/section.shared.dir.html",
        replace: true,
        controller: function($scope) {
            $scope.$on('ready-to-render', function(e, rows, cols) {
               // console.log(rows, cols);
                $scope.globalrows.rows = rows;
                $scope.cols = cols;
            });
        }
    };
})
```

### globalrows array

[image: globalrows array datastructure]

Comment: Just a hint, you use the 'E' restriction, so your directive should be used like <gold-print section="1"></grid-print>.

For the other thing, do you mean your tables are showing rows with the same data? Or both tables have the same data? Because they are getting the same data of the same service. Don't really understand the problem.

Comment: Yes, tables are showing rows with the same data. The globalarray has 2 distinct table elements in it.

Comment: Do the thing with the isolated scope and passing the data to the directive. This should work from @Pankaj Parkar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently your directive didn't create any child scope, basically it is sharing same scope among a page. And when you update data either of table, it is updating the data on both places.

Create a directive by having isolated scope like `scope: { ... }`, so that each directive will work as individual component & pass the data to directive from isolated scope properties. Here `data1` & `data2` are dynamic table data value which will be supplied by the consumer of the directive. In your case what you can do is, you should take out service call from directive `controller`, because it will make your directive more tightly couple `Component`. Instead move that out and place inside a parent controller where directive element are resides.

**Markup**

```
<grid-print section="1" columns="cols" table-data="data1"></grid-print>
<grid-print section="2" columns="cols" table-data="data2"></grid-print>
```

**Controller**

```
 // If its simple hardcoded data arriving from method then use below
 // $scope.globalrows = dataservice.getCollectionData();
 // $scope.data1 = $scope.globalrows[0];
 // $scope.data2 = $scope.globalrows[1];
 // If data is comming from promise, the do following thing.
 dataservice.getCollectionData().then(function(data){
       $scope.globalrows = data;
       $scope.data1 = $scope.globalrows[0];
       $scope.data2 = $scope.globalrows[1];
});

$scope.cols = $scope.columns; //this would be array of columns.
```

**Directive**

```
.directive("gridPrint", function($sessionStorage, dataservice) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: "components/print/templates/print.dir.html",
        replace: true,
        scope: {
           tableData: '=', //table data will set by directive consumer
           columns: '=' // no need for named attributes
        },
        link: function(scope, element, attributes){
            // do DOM manipulation here if required.            
        }
        controller: function($scope) {
            // It's possible the data is not filled yet, because you gain the data from a service (which is asynchronous), 
            //so just initialize with empty array
            if(angular.isUndefined($scope.tableData)){
              $scope.tableData = [];
            }
            if(angular.isUndefined($scope.columns)){
              $scope.columns = [];
            }
        }
    };
})
```

**template : print.dir.html**

```
<form class="form-horizontal clearfix">
<table class="grid table table-bordered">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th ng-repeat="col in columns">{{col.title}}</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
      <tr ng-repeat="row in tableData track by $index" index={{index}}>
        <td ng-repeat="col in columns">          
          <span>{{ row[col.field] }}</span>
        </td>  
      </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
</form>
```

[**Plunkr Here**](http://plnkr.co/edit/Vka74rQqXDrbLdaiMuWs?p=preview)

Comment: where would I get table-data="data1" from? I have the 2 table items in my globalarray. how do i pass it to the grid print directive?

Comment: @web_dev where you had a directive element that controller will decide which data need to be passed.. let me update an answer.

Comment: Also I want don't want to hard code columns in the markup, it has to be generated dynamically.In fact, I'm determining the number of rows and columns within another directive and want to pass it to grid print directive. is it possible?

Comment: Cleaned up some things. You have dynamic columns with the above code. Adjust the template with the attributes and give it a try.

Comment: I may be new to angular, so I still dont see how the globalrows array(that the template uses) is populated from the values that we newly added to the custom directive.

Comment: Now I get it with the modified template code. I will try and post the outcome. Thanks.

Comment: @web_dev you don't need to have two directive for this case.. one directive with isolated scope is sufficient itself. Now I can't revert what I suggested.. you should have added both directive at the time when you added question..

Comment: No issues Pankaj, the original question i posted is the problem Im trying to solve.

Comment: Nope, all im getting is blank tables now.

Comment: @web_dev let me look into it.. give me 5-10 mins.. now it seems a differnt from what you have asked :(

Comment: So this application is a multi step form with tables for collecting user inputs. The last screen is the summary (or print screen). I have an array where I'm pushing the contents of each step of the form and want to summarize all the steps on the print summary page. The original question I posted is to pull all the values stored in the globalrows array and print it on the print screen.

Comment: Any luck on the plunkr?